# Adding a D3.js Liquid Fill gauge in a Leaflet popup

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I'm trying to add a D3.js liquid fill gauge (http://bl.ocks.org/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6) in a Leaflet popup without succeeding.

Here is my code:

```js
            var map = L.map('map').setView([47.261491,-1.549244], 16);
            
            var dataCenterIcon = L.icon({
                        iconUrl: 'images/datacenter-icon.png',
                        iconSize:     [20, 20] // size of the icon
                        });
            
          L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                                maxZoom: 19,
                                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
  }).addTo(map);


            d3.json("data/datacentersSigma.json",function (data){L.geoJson(data,{
                pointToLayer: function (feature,latlng){return L.marker(latlng,{icon:dataCenterIcon});},
                onEachFeature : function (feature, layer) {

                    var div = $('<div class="popupGraph" style="width: 200px; height:200px;"><svg id="gauge"/></svg></div>')[0];
                    var popup = L.popup().setContent(div);

                    layer.bindPopup(popup);

//                    var svg = d3.select(div).select("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 200);
//                  svg.append("rect").attr("width", 150).attr("height", 150).style("fill", "lightBlue");
                    loadLiquidFillGauge("gauge",55);
                }}).addTo(map);});   
            
                
            d3.json("data/trajetsFibreDCSigma.json",function (data){
                L.geoJson(data, {
                style: function(feature){return {color : feature.properties.stroke};}
                }).addTo(map);
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Yepee</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="js/d3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/liquidFillGauge.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
<!--        <svg id="gauge"/>-->
        <script src="js/yepee.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

When I'm trying to display my map, I can't even see the markers and I've got this error:

**TypeError: d3_window(...) is null**

I can also load a liquid fill gauge on a svg element which isn't on my map.

I've tried to add just a simple svg square in the popup by following an example (http://jsfiddle.net/2XfVc/132/) and it worked.

The goal is to put that gauge in the leaflet popup and despite searching for a long time, I can't find what the problem is.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to initialize the gauge when the actual SVG element  isn't added to the DOM yet. Once the popup opens, the content gets added to the DOM, that's when you should initialize the gauge.

```
// Have same content for all your popups
var content = '<svg id="gauge" width="100" height="100"></svg>'

// Set markers with popup, include content and set value as option
new L.Marker([0, -45]).bindPopup(content, {'value': 33}).addTo(map)
new L.Marker([0, 45]).bindPopup(content, {'value': 66}).addTo(map)

// Catch popup open event
map.on('popupopen', function (e) {
    // Initialize the gauge with current popup option's value
    loadLiquidFillGauge('gauge', e.popup.options.value);
})
```

Demo on Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/2hMjBt/preview

Comment: Oh my bad ! I thought the svg element was already added. It works fine now, thank you for your help  ! :)